# Need some help understanding model and dataprovider

Tags: model, dataprovider, yii

I am new to Yii and am trying to understand it by creating a hobby web site to manage my food shopping. I am trying to create a page which lists my recipes and has a +/- button next to each recipe which when pressed updates a shopping list on the same page. All of the recipe ingredients and the shopping list is stored in an SQL database.

So far, I have a controller called ShoppingListController and in my actionIndex() function (which shows the recipes and shopping list) I am creating two dataproviders and a model (for the +/- buttons which are a form) and passing them to my view as follows:

```
        // Create a shopping list item model
        $shoppingListModel = new TblShoppingListItem;

        // Get the saved shopping list data from the shopping list table
        $shoppingDataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('TblShoppingListItem', array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'select'=>array('recipe_id', 'recipe_multiplier')), 
            'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>500)
        ));

        // Get the recipe ingredient data from the recipe models and order by recipe name           
        $recipeDataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('TblRecipeIngredient', array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'select'=>array('recipe_id', 'ingredient_id', 'ingredient_unit_id', 'ingredient_amount'),   
                'with'=>array('recipe','ingredient','ingredientUnit'),
                'together'=>true,
                'order'=>'recipe.name ASC'),
            'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>500)
        ));

        // Render the 'shoppinglist/show' page
        $this->render('show', array(
            'recipeDataProvider'=>$recipeDataProvider, 
            'shoppingDataProvider'=>$shoppingDataProvider,
            'shoppingListModel'=>$shoppingListModel
        ));
```

I am a bit confused - I seem to need the model to pass into the +/- forms, I need the first data provider so I can display my shopping list and I need the second data provider so that I can display my recipe information.

However, I am wondering do I actually need the shoppingListModel and the shoppingDataProvider (i.e. is having both bad practice)?. Could I get the information I need just from the model?. I am confused by the difference between a model and a data provider.

Comment: Are you displaying old shopping lists? Or just the current one? And what do you exactly mean by saved shopping list data? can you tell me what's the significance of recipe_multiplier? And how is the shopping list exactly related to a recipe, logically that is, how do you explain the relationship?

Comment: This question is too broad and vague to be answered. I would recommend Mewzer spend some time reading about ActiveRecord relations in Yii, that might help clear things up: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is your choice that use or not to use a dataprovider. I am using dataproviders just when I need pagination or a gridview, every other time I just use data from models.

Dataproviders give additional control options on data, but if you need just data I think you must use models.